# WebSphere, the same context root for multiple war's

Tags: java, websphere, war, websphere-8

I have a task to deploy two war files on websphere using scripting tool, but the problem is that this two wars should have the same context root's:

```
/App/Web/Start
```

and

```
/App/Web/Report
```

The context root for these wars is "/App"

But WebSphere by default throws an error than the context root is already exists, maybe You can suggest some ways to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest `/start` and `/report` as context-roots and a reverse proxy in front of your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/App/Web/Start` and `/App/Web/Report` are not the same context roots.

You can define composite context roots in your `application.xml`:

```
<context-root>/App/Web/Start</context-root>
```

Or use Apache as frontend, with ProxyPass:

```
ProxyPass /App/Web/Start/ http://localhost:9080/app1/Web/Start/
ProxyPass /App/Web/Report/ http://localhost:9080/app2/Web/Report/
```